# Unable to downgrade numpy for compatibility with librosa 0.8.1

Tags: python, numpy, pip, librosa

I need to use `librosa 0.8.1` for compatibility but cannot seem to downgrade it; or rather, I can downgrade it, but an incompatibility with the latest version of `numpy` followed by an inability to downgrade `numpy` is preventing me from using it.

I first used `pip install librosa==0.8.1` to get the version of `librosa` I needed. However, when trying to import this into my project, I'm getting a `numpy` package error.

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'complex'.
`np.complex` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `complex`. 
To avoid this error in existing code, use `complex` by itself. 
Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. 
If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.complex128` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20.
```

It seems `librosa 0.8.1` is incompatible with `numpy 1.26.4`. But, this is the version of `numpy` that was installed automatically when I ran `pip install librosa==0.8.1`. It seems this issue is [fixed](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1350) in `librosa 0.9.x` but I need the earlier version.

I tried `pip uninstall numpy` followed by `pip install numpy=1.19.2` but this failed with the error,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'
```

I tried `pip install --upgrade numpy==1.19.2` and `pip install --force-reinstall numpy==1.19.2`. I tried using `pip3` and installing a different version `numpy 1.19.5`. All had the same error. I have the latest version of `setuptools` installed.

I tried `python -m pip` even though I only have one version of python (`python 3.12.2 x64`) on my machine. This failed too.

I am not sure whether the fix lies with `setuptools` or whether there is an alternative to downgrading `numpy`. I do not mind if I cannot downgrade `numpy`, I just want to be able to use `librosa 0.8.1`, without incompatibility errors preventing me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `I have the latest version of setuptools installed.` that might just be the problem, try downgrading to a version that was aroudn when numpy 1.19.2 was released, e.g. setuptools==49.6.0. You will also need to downgrade your python version to 3.8

Comment: @FlyingTeller thank you for your comment, I will try this. Does this mean there is no way to use the latest version of Python 3 with librosa 0.8.1/numpy 1.19.2?

Comment: To answer my own question, it seems that is the case. Python 3.12 removed the distutils package, and downgrading setuptools removes distutils from there. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'` is replaced by `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'`. I'm assuming 3.11 is the highest version I can probably use, as distutils is deprecated but still there.

Answer (score 0):

if you uninstall numpy and then install `pip install librosa==0.8.1`, it will install numpy as required.

Comment: Hello, this does not work. This just installs the latest version of numpy (1.26.4) even though it is incompatible with librosa 0.8.1